# Material 3 Navigation Drawer not highlighting item for current fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, material-design

So, I'm migrating to Material 3 right now for building my app. For the first time, navigation drawer not selecting / highlighting the item I selected (It was working in material 2).

Screenshot:

[image: My App Here]
This app must selecting settings item right now, but the indicator doesn't show up

This is what I'm looking for:
[image: Example from Material 3 documentation]

I followed documentation but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**
This is my menu.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_read"
        android:title="@string/menu_read" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"
        android:title="@string/menu_about" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Attach `menu.xml` code.

Comment: @Sky attached, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap menu items into `group` and set attribute `checkableBehavior` to `single`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_read"
            android:title="@string/menu_read" />
        ...
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's highlighting now, but the hover effect doesn't appear when I clicked the menu item, how to solve this?

Comment: @raka-m-a 'hover effect' you mean ripple effect?

Comment: yes, ripple effect when it long pressed

Comment: @raka-m-a Weird behaviour, maybe you overwrote the default value? Check `<item name="colorControlHighlight">` in `themes/styles.xml`